# High suspicious traffic + connection slow and disconnecting on VPS

Tags: network-traffic

I have a problem with my VPS hosted by OVH in France: I have a high traffic. If I look at `ifconfig` it gives:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXX
           ... ... ...
          RX bytes:6561541076 (6.5 GB)  TX bytes:370590231 (370.5 MB)
```

so a bigger traffic in RX than in TX.

Next if I have a look at nethogs:

```
  PID USER     PROGRAM                                    DEV        SENT      RECEIVED
10141 alexis   sshd: alexis@pts/1                         eth0     375.118   263.438 KB
?     root     5.196.13.44:20000-5.196.13.22:59169                  0.000     50.912 KB
?     root     5.196.13.44:13003-5.196.13.22:38136                  0.000     18.305 KB
?     root     5.196.13.44:13016-5.196.13.22:38112                  0.000      0.605 KB
?     root     188.217.151.184:62559-92.222.217.15:12000            0.000      0.527 KB
?     root     66.249.78.243:36551-37.187.181.55:80                 0.000      0.434 KB
?     root     37.187.195.216:52927-37.187.55.179:80                0.000      0.434 KB
?     root     79.2.118.27:4475-37.187.53.170:34555                 0.000      0.410 KB
?     root     80.43.165.147:30378-92.222.217.231:12689             0.000      0.410 KB
?     root     94.3.174.108:23526-92.222.217.231:12689              0.000      0.410 KB
?     root     2.127.10.45:20002-92.222.217.231:12689               0.000      0.410 KB
```

So with hundreds of lines that I don't have a clue what they are and show clearly a higher RX traffic than TX. It is weird because no device is specified and no pid neither

I had a look at netstat but everything looks normal. I tried to IPTABLES-DROP everything except the SSH but problem remains

Any clue about how I can fix that problem. By the way the traffic is sometimes slow and the ping is unstable

Comment: What is your reasoning to think that this traffic is malicious? What is your reasoning that RX being higher is a bad thing? Other than that, you give us very little information to work with.

Comment: The problem is that my connection is unstable (ssh deconnections + ustable ping). So I look at nethogs and I found all these weird lines. So I wonder if I am under attack. What kind of information is missing?

Comment: What are you hosting on this server? Where are you in relation to the server (as that contributes to ping/ssh lag times)?

Comment: This server is used for Apache2 web hosting + OpenVPN server. But there are not involved since the issue remains even after I kill them. I am connected through ssh at ~ 500 km from it. the unstable ping is when I ping other VPS or addresses like google.com. In the past there used to be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

The problem was coming from one of the switches used by my hoster. My VPS was receiving many packets not intended for it. That is why I had this weird traffic with nethogs.

They fixed the problem